# MaterializeCSS input date displaying prior day

Tags: javascript, date, materialize

When I show an input field with datepicker passing in a value from my SQL data, MaterializeCSS is displaying the value as the day before.  It works if I reformat the date using slashes instead of dashes, but that is a horrible long-term solution.

Here is the code:

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker" value="2022-03-15">
```

Which will show as March 14th in MaterializeCSS and if you save, it saves it as March 14th.

Here is the CodePen showing the incorrect behavior.

https://codepen.io/programminglabs/pen/ExQxNvx

There must be a setting in JS in MaterializeCSS but I cannot find it.  I expect the issue is I need to add one microsecond.  How can I do that globally in my MaterializeCSS environment?

Comment: For me it shows 15 March. Likely "2022-03-15" is being parsed as  UTC but displayed as local, so only users west of Greenwich see the previous day. When you use the UI, it sets the local date.

Comment: @RobG Wow, that's a really good explanation of why it happens.  Is there any way to prevent that?  Any way to globally set in JavaScript to either not adjust based on the UTC or set local time to Greenwich to prevent this issue?